# Replacement for Spring Richclient Statusbar class

Tags: java

I'm currently upgrading an application from the 0.2.0 version of Spring Richclient to 1.1.0, and the class org.springframework.richclient.progress.StatusBar seems to have been removed.

I can't find any documentation on it, does anybody know if it's been renamed or if the specification has been changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. StatusBar has become org.springframework.richclient.application.statusbar.support.StatusBarProgressMonitor

The new StatusBar is in itself the previous org.springframework.richclient.progress.StatusBarCommandGroup.

Very confusing :P

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else upgrading to Spring RCP 1.0 or newer I can recommend the project's documents:
http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/1.1.0/user/upgrading/upgradingTo1.0.x.html

And yes, Spring RCP is very often confusing, especially with the extremely sparse documentation.